# design graph (diagram) for erlang system

Tags: erlang

I have been already reading 4 erlang's open source system for 3 months, and they are `rabbitmq, couchdb, gproc, jobs`.

They are totally different from my previous c# system because there are many processes and not object-oriented.

It will be better to express these systems by design graphs(diagram) rather than just source code.

Could you tell me which design graph(diagram) and tools are better for this job?

If there are some samples URL link for processes design graph(diagram), it will be better.

Answer (score 2):

for what I know a visual programming aid for Erlang has not been yet developed.

If you wanna use the graph abstraction to understand dependencies in your software you can use [XRef Tool](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/xref_chapter.html). This tool in conjuction with Erlang Digraph library can also visualize graphs of these dependencies, AFAIK.

Hope this helps!

Edit: [This article](http://www.erlang.org/euc/05/Widera.pdf) refers to a methodology to create graphs for visualize processes, message passing and program flow in Erlang.
In the end, you can also use [UML Sequence Diagram](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html)

Comment: visual programming is not important. Erlang heavily depends on messages and (static and dynamic) process, not function call and threads. How to express it? By which type of graph? I want to see one example.